# wp current_user->ID returning ID=0 in custom-php file

Tags: php, wordpress

In wordpress, I am writing a custom php file, something like below.

```
require_once (ABSPATH.'/wp-includes/pluggable.php');
require_once(ABSPATH.'/wp-load.php');
global $current_user;
echo 'ID= ' . $current_user->ID . '<br />';
#CUSTOM php CODE
```

This code is not in my functions.php file, but in a [custom].php file where I need the info to help load/update a some non-WP database items.

I am always getting ID=0 on the echo line in my code.  I have read this is related to when this is running relative to a WP init action.  But, not sure how to address in my custom php file.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Please try this you missed the function.

The call to get_currentuserinfo() places the current user's info into $userdata, where it can be retrieved using member variables.

```
<?php global $current_user;
  get_currentuserinfo();

  echo 'Username: ' . $current_user->user_login . "\n";
  echo 'User email: ' . $current_user->user_email . "\n";
  echo 'User level: ' . $current_user->user_level . "\n";
  echo 'User first name: ' . $current_user->user_firstname . "\n";
  echo 'User last name: ' . $current_user->user_lastname . "\n";
  echo 'User display name: ' . $current_user->display_name . "\n";
  echo 'User ID: ' . $current_user->ID . "\n";
?>
```

Refer [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_current_user_id/)

Comment: Thanks for the input.  I just tried several variations of adding the main function(including what is in your linked reference), but all the user infor is coming up empty.  Any other suggestions?

Comment: @tjp in WordPress which path you include the custom PHP file.

Comment: In my custom php file I am only including the two paths listed in my original post, to the pluggable.php and wp-load.php.  is there an additional path I need to be calling in?